# Map network drives checking users-list from a .txt file

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to do a small batch script what reading a list of usernames in a .txt file and if it match with the variable %username% it mount the drive.

Here's my script :

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\myfile.txt) do if /i "%%a"=="%username%" goto Label1

:Label1
net use J: \\johndoe-pc\Users\johndoe\Desktop\Test
```

The problem is I can write everything in the text file it will execute the `:Label1`.

I want it execute `Label1` only when the `%username%` variable match with the list.

Comment: When the `for /F` loop finishes, where do you think your script will continue...??

Answer (score 3):

Cmd processes the batchfile line by line. After the `for /f ...` line, there is nothing to stop this processing (like `goto :eof`), so it continues with the next line (which is just a Label, so it is being ignored). Next line to be processed is `net use...`.

There is an easier way to do what you want:

```
find "%username%" "c:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\myfile.txt" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 net use J: \\johndoe-pc\Users\johndoe\Desktop\Test
```